# Conditional array update MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection like this one:

```
{
"citizen":[
  {
    "country":"ITA",
    "language":"Italian"
  },
  {
    "country":"UK",
    "language":"English"
  },
  {
    "country":"CANADA",
    "language":"French"
  }]
}
```

I'm trying to update the collection but with a certain condition. I need to update remove an element of the array citizen if the value in the field country is longer than 3 characters.

I got that to remove an element i have to use **$pull**, to check the size of a string I have to use **$strLenCP** and **$gt** is greater than, but I'm struggling to put them together.

The result of the update should be:

```
{
"citizen":[
  {
    "country":"ITA",
    "language":"Italian"
  },
  {
    "country":"UK",
    "language":"English"
  }]
}
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
with the collection, as it is, the command:

```
db.getCollection('COLLECTION').update(  { }, {  $pull:  {"citizen": {"country": /^[\s\S]{4,}$/}}}, { multi: true })
```

works perfectly.
I tried it on another collection as this one:

```
{
"cittadino":{
  "citizen":[
    {
      "country":"ITA",
      "language":"Italian"
    },
    {
      "country":"UK",
      "language":"English"
    },
    {
      "country":"CANADA",
      "language":"French"
    }]
  }
}
```

and it doesn't update anymore. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right path:

```
db.getCollection('COLLECTION').update(  { }, {  $pull:  {"citizen": {"country": /^[\s\S]{4,}$/}}}, { multi: true })
```

[$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator takes a value or a condition. You need to use this to filter the array based on the "country" property

EDIT:

Use the [dot-notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#std-term-dot-notation) to access the nested document

```
db.getCollection('COLLECTION').update(  { }, {  $pull:  {"cittadino.citizen": {"country": /^[\s\S]{4,}$/}}}, { multi: true })
```

Comment: In your code, it matches only the strings there are exactly 4, right?

Comment: you're right, I've changed the Regex to include 4+ and the update method to delete multiple entries that match the condition

Comment: if the array is contained in another element? still do this method? because it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean, this solution works on the sample provided. You might want to modify the question.